# gem for using rdoc (or other simple markup) syntax for content of pages such as faq, about etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rdoc

I want to use rdoc (or yard or simple markup) markup for content of static pages such as faq, about etc. Had a look at high voltage from thoughtbot I would fit my need perfectly if I could also edit the content of these pages. Sort of lightweight content management.

Have googled extensively but rdoc is just a too generic word ;-)

I want to avoid using rake to generate these pages, I just want rails to render the templates and I'll cache them if performance is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is:
[Bluecloth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602040/bluecloth-isnt-working-with-rails-3) see also other library mentioned in the post. IS not really rdoc but close enough